# Unable to link Flask module to nginx through uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm sure I am missing something simple here.  I can get PART of a python/flask script to be available through nginx, but the important bits are just not working.  Here is my python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import os

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME']='localhost'


@app.route("/stuff")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

def application(environ, start_response):

    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")])
    return ["Hello World!"]
```

Here is my uwsgi start up:

```
 sudo -u www-data uwsgi -s /tmp/myApp.sock --module MyApp
```

The socket is correctly linked and available to nginx.
And here is my nginx config snippet:

```
 location /test {
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myApp.sock;
            include uwsgi_params;
    }
```

When I go to myserver/test I get the "Hello World!" like I Would expect.  But when I go to myserver/test/stuff, I ALSO get "Hello World!" rather than the contents of my index.html(Which is valid, I use it elsewhere). And if I enter myserver/test/garbage.html, I get a generic nginx 404, rather than my custom one.

Can anyone point me in a direction?

Thanks

--edit--

Thank you for the answer, it does help, but does not solve my entire issue.
Adding "--callable app" to my uwsgi startup line DOES link the uwsgi server to nginx.  Yah!  I can confirm this by the fact that my customized 404 file IS being returned by nginx.

But that 404 is ALL I can get.  I cannot get to my index.html, which is present in the same directory as the 404.html, has the same owner, and the same rights.  It is almost the same file really with slightly different text.

This MAY be a problem with expectations.  I am expecting to find my index.html at `http://(myserver)/test/stuff`  But I get a 404.

Am I looking in the wrong place?  Or is there something off in my flask, uwsgi, or nginx?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about uswgi, but surely you've not connected your `application` function with your `app` Flask object. Seems like you need to set uwsgi to point to one or the other.

Comment: Looks like you have a very different issue then. Try removing the `app.config['SERVER_NAME']='localhost'` line as it is not needed for this and isn't useful unless you need to run on a subdomain. There is likely an issue with your nginx config too, which I'll append to my answer.

Comment: I removed the SERVER_NAME as recommended.  You are right that it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're application function does not call your flask app, which is why every route returns "Hello World", 200. I'm pretty sure you have two easy options.

The first is to drop the application function and replace it with `application = app`.

The second would be to change the uwsgi line to

```
sudo -u www-data uwsgi -s /tmp/myApp.sock --module MyApp --callable app
```

which renders your application function irrelevant anyway.

You can read more about using uwsgi [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/).

**edit**

As far as my knowledge about nginx goes, your nginx config should look like this

```
location = /test { rewrite ^ /test/; }
location /test { try_files $uri @test; }
location @test {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /test;
  uwsgi_modifier1 30;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myApp.sock;
}
```

It is the same as the recommended one on the linked uwsgi page above. You seem to be running  not on the root url, so the basic config will not work.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks.  That at least gets me to /my/ 404, which means my application stack is working.  Now just to chase down hitting the actual files. (Oh, I did the second and specified the callable in the uwsgi start line.  that seems a bit cleaner.)

Comment: I started to accept this answer, but it isn't complete.  I will edit the main question, but in short, adding the callable to the uwsgi start line does link the uwsgi app to nginx, but I cannot get my actual data returned yet.  Updating main question with details

Comment: I tried that same nginx config at first and was having trouble getting nginx to even start, so I trimmed it down.  I am not an nginx expert by any means.  I will try hacking away at that a bit.

Comment: Ok, reset my location info as recommended, and I am seeing no difference. my custom 404 is still coming up for all GETs that start .../test  (even .../testXXX).  I do get the nginx default 404 for file requests outside of that branch.

Comment: I'm no nginx expert either. You should get a 404 with your custom error page for every page except `/test/stuff`. Try adding `print request.path` to the 404 handler and see what paths the app is trying to find. The app is partially working, since the 404 page comes up, but something is wrong with the routes or some other piece.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  The combination of missing --callable and missing nginx configuration was what was stalling me.  (I also had some permissions issues and a few assumptions in my code that were not valid for a production environment, but those are outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: I'm really glad you got it figured out.